audit logs of all launched applications for a given user in Azure Entra ID?
Using Microsoft Azure, how do you audit all launched applications for a given user session? For example, if I am a logged in user with an active session, and I browse to https://www.microsoft365.com/apps, and launch an app from that portal, where is this recorded? I have tried the following areas:
https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants/UserManagementMenuBlade/~/SignIns
https://compliance.microsoft.com/auditlogsearch

The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. Click here
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as Serverfault
, and Microsoft Q&A
for immediate help. Thanks!
